# $ref to external open-api spec in dependency possible?

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to use the $ref in an openapi file to point to a shared api spec.
This api spec is imported as a dependency in my spring project.

Is it possible to reference this as it is inside a jar file?
Is there another dependecy I can use for this?
I am using the openapi generator atm

I have tried multiple options but I keep getting the error:
Unable to load RELATIVE ref

In short: i want to reference one api spec from inside another and both are dependencies

Comment: Which version of `openapi-generator` are you using?

Comment: We decided for now against it. We could not host the file itself and wanted to have it via a dependency and we did make it work by using a plugin to extract the file from the dependecy but in the end it was not desired because the shared $ref could not be linted properly